# Какой ключ необходим для открытия Chromium browser в полноэкранном режиме (режиме киоск)?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, chromium

Задача следующая: открывать определенный адрес Chomium-Browser с помощью `.sh` в режиме kiosk.

Ключи

```
chromium-browser --enable-kiosk-mode http://www.google.com
chromium-browser ---kiosk http://www.google.com
/usr/bin/chromium-browser %U --kiosk http://www.google.com
```

не работают.

Запуск на Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (на NVIDIA p3450), версия Chromium 75.0.3770.90. 
Решал ли кто нибудь такую задачу?

Answer (score 2):

Проверил на Manjaro 18.0.4; Chromium 75.0.3770.142. Работает.

`chromium --kiosk`

Можете ещё попробовать так:

`chromium --window-size=1920,1080 --start-fullscreen`

Естественно, браузер при этом не должен быть запущен, иначе откроется новая вкладка вместо нового сеанса.

Comment: Оба варианта рабочие. Проблема была в скрипте и запущенном браузере. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю свой вариант параметров запуска Chromium, который используется у меня я в работе на десятке киосков.

```
while true; do
    cp -fr /home/kiosk/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences.0 /home/kiosk/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
    chromium-browser \
    --kiosk \
    --start-maximized \
    --host-resolver-retry-attempts=0 \
    --dns-prefetch-disable \
    --disable-async-dns \
    --disable-application-cache \
    --disable-restore-background-contents \
    --login-screen-size="1280,1024" \
    --disable-new-tab-first-run \
    --enable-vertical-tabs \
    --disable-restore-session-state \
    --disable-translate \
    --incognito \
    --proxy-server=localhost:8080 "$URL";
    sleep 1s;
done
```

В свое время столкнулся с проблемой, что периодически броузер начинал запускаться в оконом режиме и помогало только очистка папки `.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`.

Решил проблему через сохранение копии заранее исправной Preference-папки, из которой, при каждом запуске броузера, заменяется содержимое файлов в рабочей Preference-папке.